# Return bool from js function which executes ajax request

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have issue, that `var x = isCustomerInWarehouse(customerNumber, url)` is always **undefined**. I don't know how to rewrite this function to behave with `boolean` return type.

```
function isCustomerInWarehouse(customerNumber, url) {

    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: 'POST',
        data: { customerNumber: customerNumber },
        cache: false,
        async: false
    })

        .done(function (data) {

            if (data.result) {
                return true;             
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        })

        .fail(function () {
            alert('Ajax error happened.')
        });  

};
```

any idea ? Im not against any other javascript library for calling ajax, such as **fetch** or **axios**.

**second attempt**

```
function isCustomerInWarehouse(customerNumber, url) {
    var returnValue = false;

    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: 'POST',
        data: { customerNumber: customerNumber },
        cache: false,
        async: false // does not matter what is here :/
    })

        .done(function (data) {

            if (data.result) {
                returnValue = true;             
            } else {
                returnValue = false;
            }
        })

        .fail(function () {
            alert('Ajax error happened.')
        });  

    return returnValue;
};
```

but the value of **isWarehouse** `var isWarehouse = isCustomerInWarehouse(customerNumber, url)` is

[image]

It is becoming an absurd problem, but I still don't know how to solve it :/

Answer (score -1):

You have not The return statement ;) it's first, and second thing you shouldn't using jquery ajax. Consider use fetch api or axios.

EDIT:

```js
function isCustomerInWarehouse(customerNumber, url) {
    return fetch(url, {
      method: "POST",
      cache: "no-cache",
      body: JSON.stringify({
        customerNumber
      })
    })
        .catch(() => alert("Ajax error happened."))
        .then(data => data.result);
};
```

This function returns [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)
with data.result. What do you suppose is in data.result in your code?

Comment: Can you please provide an example ?

Comment: btw, the function has return statement, why down vote ?

Comment: isCustomerInWarehouse has not return statement. Callback provided to .done has return

Comment: It still does not work, can you please provide working code example ?

Comment: $.ajax is asynchronous, you cannot just set returnValue and return it because a return will execute before $.ajax be done. You must use Promise, I'll write the code in a hour